# dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES Vs dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

It seems bit weird to me

When I do

```
UIViewController *pv = self.presentingViewController;
[pv dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [pv presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

My app crashes

and when I do

```
UIViewController *pv = self.presentingViewController;
[pv dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [pv presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

My app runs smoothly.

Can anyone please explain the reason?

I'm calling the presentViewController: in completion block in both the cases.

Comment: Which is log message about crash?

Comment: Line 1: Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <******> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Line 2: transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set! (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController: 0x102510ce0>)

I'm putting the presentViewController: call in completion block in both the cases.